# Allow numericInput() in Shiny interactive web application to take input with commas (for European users)

Tags: r, shiny

In a Shiny interactive web application (link to source [here](https://github.com/jrosen48/shinykonfound), we use `numericInput()` for users to enter values which are used (see `ui.R`, or, here's a snippet):

```
  sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
          numericInput("unstd_beta", "Estimated Effect", 2),
          numericInput("std_error", "Standard Error", .4),
          numericInput("n_obs", "Number of Observations", 100),
          numericInput("n_covariates", "Number of Covariates", 3),
          actionButton("button", "Run"),
          width = 2
      ),
```

This has basically worked fine, *until* users from Europe (Germany) try to enter values using a comma (,) instead of a decimal (.) to enter values, i.e.:

```
7,06
```

instead of

```
7.06
```

This doesn't work, as `numericInput()` does not allow commas. Is there any (easy-ish) way to allow users from Europe to enter such values (`7,06`)?

If not, we can imagine work-arounds (i.e., allow the input to be of any type (i.e., strings), and then process the strings in turn; but that's not as desirable to us.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `textInput()` instead and replace comma by dot with `gsub()` :

```
library(shiny)

if (interactive()) {

  ui <- fluidPage(
    textInput("number", "Number", "0,4"),
    verbatimTextOutput("value")
  )
  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$value <- renderText({ as.numeric(paste(gsub(",", ".", input$number))) })
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```